# INSERT embedded in INSERT INTO SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to do an INSERT INTO SELECT statement, with a further INSERT embedded in the SELECT.  The reason is that I need to make a copy of a foreign key and use the new row id in the outside insert.  Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Contracts ( 
  JobId, 
  InvoiceNumber
  ExpensesId)
SELECT 
  j.Id,
  j.InvoiceNumber, 
  (INSERT INTO Expenses (Bus, Toll) SELECT Bus, Toll FROM Expenses WHERE Id = j.ExpensesId)
FROM Jobs j
```

This SQL does not run, as the INSERT does not return anything, but is there a way to do this, or a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it quite like that.

I think this may be what you're trying to do?

```
INSERT INTO Contracts ( 
  JobId, 
  InvoiceNumber
  ExpensesId)
SELECT 
  j.Id,
  j.InvoiceNumber, 
  j.ExpensesID
FROM Expenses 
   INNER JOIN Jobs j ON expenses.Id = j.ExpensesId
```

If you need to copy the expenses row, you need to do that first, and use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` to get the new ID.

```
declare @expenseid int = -- your expense ID
declare @newid int

INSERT Expenses (Bus, Toll)
SELECT Bus, Toll FROM Expenses WHERE Id = @expenseID
SELECT @newID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO Contracts ( 
  JobId, 
  InvoiceNumber
  ExpensesId)
SELECT 
  j.Id,
  j.InvoiceNumber, 
  @newID
FROM Expenses 
WHERE Id = @expenseID
```

If you want to do a batch

```
DECLARE @inserts table(expenseid int, jobid int)

INSERT Expenses (Bus, Toll)
OUTPUT inserted.id, Jobs.ID INTO @inserts
SELECT Bus, Toll FROM Expenses 
       INNER JOIN Jobs ON Jobs.ExpenseID = Expenses.ID

INSERT Contracts (JobID, InvoiceNumber, ExpensesID)
SELECT j.ID, j.InvoiceNumber, i.ExpenseID
FROM Jobs j
     INNER JOIN @inserts I on j.ID = i.jobid
```

... or something like that - not quite sure I compeletely understand your data structures.

Comment: Not quite.  I need to copy the expenses record, get the new Id and use that in the outside insert.  This uses the existing Expenses record.

Comment: Thanks for the edit!  Unfortunately this means doing it one record at a time with a cursor.  I was hoping to do it in a single batch, but yes, this is the answer if there's no other option.

Comment: @ChrisWallis No, you can do it as a batch. Let me edit further.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write insert in select statement. It does not return a column field or object